# OpenCV Contours not returning properly

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying to segment the input image using OpenCV. The aim is to seperate the image into different bounding rectangles (ex: one rectange for Aroma, one for CAFE and so on) I would later take each bounded rectangle and try to identify the text within it.

The problem I am facing is for certain images, the findContours function is not working as expected. I am getting the different ROI's but it is not what i am expecting. PFB some samples. I am getting some zoomed ouputs. Can somebody help me in figuring out what I am missing

I need to get AROMA in an image, CAFE in another image, 1211 in another image and so on ?

Number of Contours : 108

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import image
image = cv2.imread('receipt-1.jpg')
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

#grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray,cmap='gray')
plt.show()

# Remove blur
image = cv2.medianBlur(image,5) 

# Adaptive
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,1,1,11,2)
thresh_color = cv2.cvtColor(thresh,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


#dilation
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(img_dilation)
plt.show()


# find contours
_,ctrs,_ = cv2.findContours(img_dilation,cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Sort contours
#sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs,key=cv2.contourArea)

# print rect
idx = 0
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    #if cv2.contourArea(ctr)>1000:
    # Get bounding box
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    #print x,x+w,y,y+h
    #print ctr
    # Getting ROI
        roi = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        #cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.jpg', roi)
        idx+=1
        plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
        plt.imshow(roi)
        plt.show()
    #plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    # show ROI
```

[image: Original Image]
[image: Merged Image]

Comment: This might help, on line `_,ctrs,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` try using `cv2.CV_RETR_LIST` instead of `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`

Comment: Thank you. Now I get better results. Is there a way I can get the words seperately like say AROMA in an image and CAFE in an image and so on ?

Comment: Are the bounding rectangles now being around around 'AROMA' and 'cafe' ?

Comment: Please, provide an original input image, so we can reproduce this.

Comment: I have attached the original image. Please check this out

Comment: @tkhurana96 : I have replaced the code a little bit and used cv2.adaptiveThreshold. Now the contours are better, still I am getting some zoomed contours and not the expected results

Comment: @AdithyaKumar What's the point of the dilation there? You're not using the result... Took a few moments to notice that, but now it's fairly obvious -- just thresholding is hardly going to turn all the words into contiguous blobs.

Comment: @Aditya Kumar can you post the updated results that you are getting now ?

Comment: @tkhurana96 :  I have updated the latest code and images

Comment: @DanMašek : Thank you Dan. I have incorporated your fixes. Now it is a lot better. But still I see a lot of small blobs. There are a total 108 contours and most of them are very small with nothing major to show(Like Top Left image in Picture 2). Now I see many parts of the image. But I still dont see the items and the amount (Like Ginger Carrt Soup, House Salad, 6.79 etc). How do I restrict my output to show only major contours ?

Comment: @tkhurana96 : I have uploaded the latest iamges after I made fixes by Dan.  Can you please check this out

Comment: @AdithyaKumar There seems to be some noise (some most likely artefacts of JPEG) that the adaptive threshold seems to pick up. See if you can filter that out. I would consider dilating only horizontally. The some heuristics per contour, to drop ones that don't make sense. I wouldn't expect it to merge all the words together, for example "York" has a huge gap between the first two symbols. You will need to devise some way to merge adjacent boxes together -- fonts are fixed width, so can take advantage of that. In light of that, it may be better break it down to characters and merge them after.

Comment: @AdithyaKumar Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/sTJzS16B) already seems to do a lot better job. It's only a quick sketch tho.